# Storing custom data on a prefab instance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that generates a star with planets.

Each planet will have information associated with it, for instance "type" (lava, rocky etc).

I have the trigger set up for when the mouse is over a planet working:

```
ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        print (hit.collider.name);
    }
```

I am instantiating planets with:

```
GameObject planetClone = Instantiate (planet, pos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

How do I attach the string variable "type" to an instanced prefab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a script to the prefab with required parameters and a method to pass them as an example

```
// ScriptA 
String type;
public void SetType(String _type){
    type = _type;
}
```

Attach ScriptA to the prefab, After instantiating the prefab, You can use

```
ScriptA scriptA = (ScriptA) planetClone.GetComponent<ScriptA>();
scriptA.SetType("Data you want to pass comes here");
```

This attached script will be belonging to instantiated GameObject and properties will be associated with it! You may refer [unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that but is so obvious!